# How to create a larger frame in Java

Tags: java, swing, size

I am drawing a coordinate system with weight, height =10000*10000 on a frame. It too big, my graph  can't fully display. I try to draw on scroll but it's lag. I want to display my graph on a frame 10000*10000, fit with my screen computer to print screen. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to scale you graph. You know, Earth is very big but it fits map that can be shown on a screen of your smart phone :)

This means that if for example you want to show rectangle of 10000*10000 on screen that has (for example) 1000 pixels you have to scale your picture 10 times.

Comment: Thank you, i used scale(0.1,0.1). When i used draw(x/10, y/10, x'/10, y'/10), its result is similar to scale.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Set the size of the JFrame on which you are displaying the graph to the desired size.

```
  setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

where WIDTH and HEIGHT are in pixels.

OR

Option 2: Scale the drawing. That is, simply divide each dimension in the drawing by 2 to make it half the size.